# Swift app crashes when presenting cached View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiviewcontroller, segue

My iOS app has two ViewControllers (VCs).  When I press a button on VC A, it presents VC B.  When I press a button on VC B it presents VC A.  This was fine.  However, it turned out that it was creating a new instance of each view controller every time you switched, which messed up some of the functionality of my app.  I tried to change this.

As you can see below, I am only creating a new instance of a VC if one doesn't exist already.  I am saving VC A in VC B and vice versa.

VC A file:

```
var vcB: BViewController?

func leftPresentVC() {
    if(vcB == nil) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        vcB = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcB") as! BViewController
        vcB?.transitioningDelegate = transition
        vcB?.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        vcB?.vcA = self
    }
    present(vcB!, animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

VC B file:

```
var vcA: AViewController?

func rightPresentVC() {
    if(vcA == nil) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        vcA = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcA") as! AViewController
        vcA?.transitioningDelegate = transition
        vcA?.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    }
    if let vcA = vcA {
        present(vcA, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
}
```

The functions leftPresentVC and rightPresentVC are getting called on button press.

So the problem is this.  When I launch the app, VC A loads as planned.  I click a button and VC B presents as planned.  Then I click a button to go to VC A and the app crashes.  I get an error in `present(vcA, animated: true, completion: {})` of VC B saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS and it gives a memory address.  Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are presenting one upon the same.

Just dismiss VCb and you will get VCa

```
 dismiss(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Oh true, didn't know you couldn't present an existing view controller.  This fixed the problem.